# Statistics about Mobile App Users

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, android-app, ios-app, statistics

I am interested in knowing the statistics about the number of people using the mobile platorm.

These specifics would be interesting:

1. Number of people who exclusively use the Mobile App only
2. When both Mobile App and Desktop are used what proportion of time is spent in each?
3. What is the Mobile App primarily used for?

I think this statistics will help understand the impact Mobile apps have made in the usage of Stack Exchange sites.

Please feel free to comment on what other statistics users would like to see related to Mobile Applications (iOS and Android).

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am asking for percentage. How can I see the percentage and not just the questions themselves? Of course unless you expect me to scour through all the questions?

Comment: And the [advanced search tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) can help you filter that down even further... for example if you wanted to get the number of new feature requests only since the apps were released you can date constrain the results.

Comment: [18,339 feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on MSE currently. [191 also tagged with ios-app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+ios-app) = ~1%. And the android app would be basically the same proces.

Comment: I fixed my previous comment because I had a bad link - I linked back here instead of to the search results.  Now that is very unscientific as it will include only undeleted content and includes duplicates.  But it should give you a rough idea.  You can probably filter it down some more by removing closed questions from an advanced search.

Comment: I am thinking that if a page is made with detailed statistics, won't it be better if it involves answer to question 4 too?

Comment: The [Quantcast stats](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc) are a good place to start.  In the graph mobile app is a green line, approximately 0.18px thick.  I think it's safe to assume that the answer to #1 is around zero. #2 and #3 are questions we're also exploring but I can tell you people are doing pretty much everything (asking, answering, commenting).

Comment: Can you provide that as an answer? I will accept.

Comment: @BrianNickel Please post that as the answer. It was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

As Brian said [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246524/statistics-about-mobile-app-users#comment809882_246524):

> the [Quantcast stats](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc) are a good place to start.
>
> In the graph mobile app is a green line, approximately 0.18px thick. I think it's safe to assume that the answer to #1 is around zero. #2 and #3 are questions we're also exploring but I can tell you people are doing pretty much everything (asking, answering, commenting).

Sample screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: I try to use the mobile app but it takes a super long time to load my feed, over 15 minutes, so i don't bother...