# Q&A blank in Stack Exchange Android app v1.0.95 - S10e/Android 10

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app

Recently upgraded to a Samsung S10e and
Android 10, but all Q&A in the Stack Exchange app v1.0.95 are blank.

The title and comments are visible, but question/answer posts are just white space. Accessing the *About* page in the app is also blank.

I tried clearing data, cache and re-installing the app, but I still get the same behaviour.

[image: Blank Q&A]
[image: Blank About]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248277/how-does-one-report-a-bug-for-stack-exchange-android-app suggests bugs should be posted here - I can't report a bug through the app as the about page displays nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app intermittently shows blank body in questions and answers (multiple sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s)

Comment: The app is now working correctly after a 2nd re-install. The about page states "Bugs or feature requests should be reported on Meta Stack Exchange and tagged android-app" so why is my question considered off-topic?

Comment: Also be aware that the app is no longer being maintained, and probably wont ever be again. Using the responsive fulk site view is a great alternative on mobile devices.

Comment: Until SE *formally* drops support for the app, I don't see why it needs to be closed. While development is on permanent hiatus - a breaking bug would still get looked at. Maybe as a dupe but ehhh. Also, posting a bug report using the app would post it *here*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek SE [*has* formally dropped support for the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/154798/21), for glitches that require changing the app's code. Only those which can be fixed server-side (e.g. an API change) are supported.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, and I heared the mobile site is also scheduled for discontinuation. Responsive design it shall be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Comment: You have **lots** of bugs to reject now. O.o

Comment: Will there be any way of getting notifications on our phones for new inbox messages? That's the only thing I (and many others) ever used the app for. Have you perhaps considered the possibility of offering a little widget instead of a full app that would show a notification and then would open the web page in the browser?

Comment: @terdon and others who want such a thing: look in [this list](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bapp%5d%20notifications%20is%3aq), might find something that still works in there.

Comment: Can you consider completely removing the app from the stores if there's no plan on maintaining them anyway?

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica almost certainly a cost-cutting thing.

Comment: @OrangeDog Closing the public Q&A completely would also cut costs considerably, but obviously it would not make sense as long as SE Inc. see it as their core business. Killing off the native apps indicates a deeper shift than budget issues. SE Inc. is giving up a lot page views, potential user interactions, and all the ad revenue associated with that. It’s alarming they don’t consider public Q&A important enough anymore.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica native app development was killed off ages ago, and the app doesn't have ads (or maybe it does and my rep is sufficient to not see them?).

Comment: @OrangeDog Active development has indeed stopped years ago. And you’re right, no ads are directly shown through the app, but a lot of content — questions, answers and comments — is generated through the native apps, and that drives all forms of traffic.

Comment: @OrangeDog I have no direct evidence, no. But generally native apps make up a considerable amount of traffic in our day and age. It’s reasonable to assume the SE network with its 150 websites is no different.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica [here's the stats from 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248590/155659)

Comment: @OrangeDog Most of my interactions, including this conversation, are though the native iOS app, which has been surviving with very little maintenance (last updated 2 years ago). The Android app has over 500K installs and about 20K reviews. In addition, the recent comments suggest how badly the app will be missed just on Android.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica StackOverflow alone is getting over 100K new posts (questions and answers) and around 60M visits a week. App users are a tiny minority, app users who post frequently even more so.

Comment: @OrangeDog Surely 5 years old stats cannot reflect the overwhelming shift to mobile devices and native apps in general that has taken place over this time?

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica and what about the overwhelming shift from native apps to mobile-first websites in that same time period? Those 5-year-old stats should've only decreased for an abandoned app. Compare 500K installs **ever** to 100K posts to *one* site **every week**. If you want to claim that a significant amount (e.g. 20%+) of content comes from this app you need to provide some extraordinary evidence.

Comment: What is "the responsive web site"?  Do you mean we should use a regular mobile browser to access the main web site for Stack Overflow, (Server Fault, Super User) and the Stack Exchange sites?  Or does it have some other significance lost on dinosaurs like myself?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it means use your browser. You may need to scroll to the bottom of the page and click "Enable responsiveness"

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica I don't know if you have been following the SE mobile app development on Meta SE, but they don't have (and not intended to hire) mobile devs anymore. Also, as a regular SE Android app user, the mobile apps are good only for experience SE users, but worst for new users because they don't provide any guidance (not even a link to help center).... like, "Ask a question? Sure, just type and post it. Oops, it's off-topic, but I don't know because the app doesn't tell me anything!" And honestly... I only use the app for push notification, lunch-time browsing, and commenting...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I have not. But it's clear SE.inc is putting its faith in the "responsive" website. I'm not advocating any technology over another. I'm just saying that in my personal (experienced) opinion the site does not measure up to the mobile app and that's a damn shame.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica sure, I share a similar sentiment that the app is still more convenient than mobile web, and while it has some interesting features (multiple drafts? Though there's also feature discrepancy between the Android and iOS version), it still lacks sufficient moderation features that the experience SE users have asked before (e.g. review queue, delete vote).

Comment: To me, this is not an answer. Ok, development was discontinued. *Why?* Ads? Not supporting everything the site does, such as reviews? I keep the app because I prefer (instant) push notifications over a (delayed) email digest. And until Apple implements Web Push Notifications (and SE adds them), I’m basically SOL. So what gives?

Comment: @ColeJohnson https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/the-stack-exchange-mobile-app-has-a-bug-is-missing-a-feature-how-can-i-repor

Comment: If you’re not supporting the app anymore, should you continue nagging the users to install the app whenever they visit the site? https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=2910EBD8-FAD4-4E80-BFCB-94071D053A53.jpeg

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar if you are seeing ads for the mobile app, can you please add screenshots on a new post? I agree, we may want to reconsider showing ads like that anymore

Comment: @yaakov-ellis there’s a screenshot in my comment, must I open a new issue?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar first, the screen shot isn't a proper shared dropbox link - maybe it works for you, but it doesnt work for anyone else (try it in an incognito browser to see what I mean). second, it is extremely difficult to track feature requests in comments of tangentially-related posts. If you put it in a separate post, it makes follow up much more likely.