# Should mobile app questions be closed now that the apps are officially retired?

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons, mobile-app, bug-reports

Today, Yaakov Ellis, a Stack Exchange staff member, [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/336163) in response to an app bug report that,

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Should we now close app bug reports? I'm thinking about either closing them as "can no longer be reproduced" (as they cannot be reproduced any more by any current software) or as duplicates of a canonical "The app is broken???->The apps are no longer supported, please use the responsive website kthx." post, but wanted to see what the community consensus is on the disposition of these posts (of which there are many, both recent and not-so-recent).

Comment: We could also mark the related tags as "do not use". This could alleviate the number of questions we would have to close (provided the questioners actually read the tag descriptions).

Comment: A confounding issue that's not helping is that the [app is still available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en_GB) in the Google Play store without any qualification that it's not being updated. As a matter of professionalism, surely it should be withdrawn? (Separate issue, I suppose).

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. That's a bit complicated to resolve. After the lead Android developer resigned last year, SE no longer has access to the account which published the app.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Very interesting, I didn't know that. I can't think of a set of circumstances where that could have come about that doesn't reflect badly on SE. Could just be a lack of imagination on my-part though.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow I managed to miss this question, but the problem being addressed was the main reason I started a canonical post: [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232) which has been extensively edited by the community and nowadays is used as dupe target for almost all new [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) questions. According to [one of Shog9's SEDE queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1430005/all-duplicates-for-post?OriginalPostId=348075) found by @zcoop98, 70 times already. So my observation is that we've chosen the

> as duplicates of a canonical "The app is broken???->The apps are no longer supported, please use the responsive website kthx." post

way.

Comment: [SEDE pulls 70 right now](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1430005/all-duplicates-for-post?OriginalPostId=348075), though I'm not sure whether that truly accounts for every one or not. Still, that's a lot!

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps just have "archived" questions added so if someone is using an older version for whatever reason, they can still find the solutions to asked questions, but have someway for people that are using the most up-to-date versions don't have to sift through a ton of outdated questions. As this is pretty common with how fast updates can happen with mobile projects.

Comment: "As this is pretty common with how fast updates can happen with mobile projects." There will be no more updates on the mobile apps.