# Why can't I delete my answer in the Stack Exchange App?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I recently answered the wrong question, and tried to delete the answer. However, in the "Stack Exchange" App, there is no button for deleting a answer as on the website, also not at the button labeled "More". Why is this?

Here the screenshot from the web version with the "Delete" Button.

[image: Here the screenshot from the web version with the "Delete" Button.]

Here the mobile version.

[image: Here the mobile version]

And here the "More" Submenu.

[image: And here the "More" Submenu]

Comment: There is no ongoing development for the app('s). This has been for a few years now.

Comment: @Luuklag there won't be any further development, ever, and it's [official](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/152859)