# Sign up using Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

Unable to register through the application.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 12.4.5 (Build 16G161)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The apps are no longer maintained. Do not expect a fix. Use the responsive site instead.

Comment: To make it clear, what @Luuklag means is that the only way to use Stack Exchange properly is via a browser: if on mobile device, you can use any browser app, personally I recommend to install Chrome app and use it.

Comment: @Luuklag The application is more convenient than the site. Will the application support not be renewed?

Comment: No the app is long dead, and there are no signs of that ever Changing. I find the responsive site perfectly useable. You can click "enable responsiveness" in the footer of the site, after you clicked view desktop site.

Comment: Then it needs to be removed from the relevant stores. New questions will continue to appear here about it (especially if the app advises it) otherwise.

Comment: Make sure to click the "full site" link in the footer if you are on the site on a mobile device. The full site is responsive and will replace both the mobile app and mobile theme and it has the same features (if not more) as the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342029/282094), see this text: "2020-01-13: The mobile apps (both android and iOS) are [declared as officially obsolete, and will not be getting any more builds, even for breaking bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028). This also applies to parts of the API that are used by the mobile apps but are not part of the public API.".