# Will the Android app be receiving any future updates?

Tags: discussion, support, android-app

Will there be a new version of the Android app? It's been without any update for a long time and it doesn't seem to be working really well.

Answer (score 11):

On January 13 2020, Yaakov Ellis, a Stack Exchange staff member, [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/336163) in response to an app bug report that,

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

The answer thus appears to be "no".

Comment: But does anyone know why is that?

Comment: @ErgativeMan A long time ago, the people responsible for app development were redelegated to other teams as part of a business restructuring. They later resigned from the company.