# Hidden text in activities

Tags: bug, ios-app

See screen shot...

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone11,6)
- OS Version: Version 13.3.1 (Build 17D50)
  [image]

Comment: Unfortunately your bug report is futile, since the iOS app won't be supported anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will the 'Mobile apps' be receiving any future updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344320/282094), neither Android nor iOS Mobile apps are getting any updates or accepting bug reports. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/282094

Comment: I don't agree with closing everything as duplicate. Reopened. Correct way is to decline all the bug reports.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, any bug reports regarding the SE iOS-app are futile.

It's officially deprecated as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343603/186472):

> According to a January 13, 2020 answer by Yaakov Ellis ♦,
>
> > We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There
> >     will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app
> >     (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the
> >     responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the
> >     user experience for mobile users.
>
> The answer thus appears to be "no".