# Connect Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ios-app

I already have a Stack Overflow account (logged with GitHub) and I saw I can use the Stack Exchange app to receive my notifications, so I have installed the app, but when I try to link, it made me a new account.

Answer (score 2):

The apps are [unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344319/336163). Yaakov Ellis (quoted in an answer in the linked question) recommends that you should use the responsive mobile site instead.