# Dark mode in Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

This is a major shortcoming of the app in not including a dark theme option. I've been using the Dark Mode add-on in Firefox for desktop but on the app there's no way to escape the unnecessarily bright theme.

Please bring in a dark theme to the app.

Comment: The app [is no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/437864)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As sempaiscuba said in the comments, the Stack Exchange Android application isn't supported anymore.

You can instead use Opera's dark mode or Firefox + some dark theme extension such as Dark Reader:

[image]

[image]