# A problem in the Stack Exchange app

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-exchange

For the past few days, when I click on the notification icon in the Stack Exchange Android app, it is closing suddenly.

So to view any notification regarding my post/comments, I need to go the profile first and then click the post. OR, I need to open the Stack Exchange site in Chrome. What's happening?

Comment: Sorry, the Stack Exchange app is no longer supported.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog means what? I didn't get your comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Q&A blank in Stack Exchange Android app v1.0.95 - S10e/Android 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341964/qa-blank-in-stack-exchange-android-app-v1-0-95-s10e-android-10) - That's another bug, but the answer explain why it won't be fixed.

Comment: I wish this is not true! I love this app more than any other app installed on my device.  :-(