# Email app download badges should be modernized

Tags: support, status-declined, android-app, ios-app, email

For the first one, the up-to-date design is available [here](https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store), and there also should be a newer version of Google's with a sans-serif font.

[image]

Comment: ... or they should stop showing those buttons altogether, since the apps are not supported anymore...

Comment: to back up Glorfindel's statement, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/299995 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! As pointed out in comments, we don't actively support the apps any more so we're not going to update the icons but we'll remove them from the emails instead. We certainly don't want to continue advertising an unsupported platform in our emails. We thought we'd dropped these from our email campaigns but it looks like we missed some.

We'll get this cleared up shortly.