# Remove Stack Exchange mobile app download buttons from emails

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, ios-app, email

Why are the Stack Exchange mobile app download buttons still appearing in emails?  This screenshot:

[image]

Confirms that.  [These](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/798831) [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076/798831) posts all say that the Stack Exchange mobile app is no longer supported, and that first one was from eight months ago.  Can we please remove those buttons?

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out in [ShadowWizard's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354772/798831), the text pointing to the download buttons should also be removed.

Comment: The Android app has also been removed, so that link is now 404.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog The link in the email, you mean?  Not in my post?

Comment: Yes, in the email.

Comment: @Sonic all the more reason to remove.  It's just taking up space now.

Comment: That kinda makes me sad, even if it was inevitable. And there's still no good way to get notifications other than that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who brought this to our attention. We've removed the mobile app icon from all of our email templates.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just to avoid an embarrassing mistake, the whole part that refers to the mobile apps should go away, not just the download buttons:

[image: revised screenshot with the whole mobile apps part marked]