# User profile - unresponsive remove button on permission for mobile app access

Tags: bug, android-app, user-accounts, se-applications

On my PC with the web interface I was nosing around in the profile to see if anything had changed or been prettified and chanced upon the [applications menu](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/apps/55743#), for those apps with permission to remotely access accounts:

[image: Text box with two buttons, one for android app access the other for Q pixel access.]

A couple of phone-upgrades ago I did use the app for a while, but since its [deprecation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341964/qa-blank-in-stack-exchange-android-app-v1-0-95-s10e-android-10/342028#342028) no longer intend to use it.

**The issue:**

Clicking the remove button for the mobile app - this has the effect of making the page jump to the top and an outline appear around the button. It clearly stays enabled by its continued presence and the persistence of the "remove" button.

*Now, this probably won't be a problem, but if my old phone with the app should find its way into the wrong hands (highly improbable).... should we not be able to cut-off access to this method of meddling with accounts? (Presumably the button was intended to have functionality beyond "page-up").*

Comment: Already reported: [Removing granted access to an Application is no longer working](/q/370293/289905). Related: [The site settings section of user preferences is now fully responsive](/q/369819/289905); there’s also a related bug about being unable to delete logins: [this answer](/a/369929/289905) and [Cannot delete a login](/q/369949/289905).